# Choosing SQLite database name from string resource

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, android-resources

I have separate databases for different languages in my app. While creating the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class, I am passing the `DB_Name` in constructor, as below

```
private static final String DB_NAME = "DB_en.sqlite";

public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.myContext = context;
}
```

Now, when I want to change the language, I need to pass `"DB_zh.sqlite"` to get the other language. I stored the DB names in `/res/values` as String resources for different language, so based on the locale it will take the name. However, how to pass the string resource to the constructor since I am passing the `private static final String DB_NAME = "DB_en.sqlite";`? I want this value to come from string resource instead.

Below is my complete Database code

```
public class MyDatabase {

    protected static final String TAG = "My Database";
    protected DataBaseHelper mDbHelper;
    protected SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    protected static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DB_en.sqlite";
    protected static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    protected final Context mCtx;

    public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // The Android's default system path of your application database.
    private final String DB_PATH = Environment.getDataDirectory()
            + "/data/com.tss.in.android.materialcompatibility/databases/";

    private static final String DB_NAME = "DB_en.sqlite";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private final Context myContext;

    /**
     * Constructor Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in
     * order to access to the application assets and resources.
     * 
     * @param context
     */     
    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context, String dbName) {
        super(context, dbName, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if (dbExist) {
            // do nothing - database already exist
        } else {
            this.getWritableDatabase();

            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            } finally {
                this.close();
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            //String NAME = myContext.getResources().getString(R.string.dbname);
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            File dbFile = new File(myPath);
            return dbFile.exists();
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            // database does't exist yet.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        // Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        this.getWritableDatabase();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the `super()` constructor call, you can replace `DB_NAME` with `context.getString(R.string.db_name)` and remove `DB_NAME` altogether.

For the database from assets problem, consider using [sqlite-asset-helper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) instead of the broken code you now have that is based on an ancient blog post.

Comment: ,hi ,the DB_NAME is mentioned in many places in the code should i change that too? and should i remove  private static final String DB_NAME = "DB_en.sqlite"; ???

Comment: Hi i changed to context.getString(R.string.db_name) everywhere, when the app starts for first time its working fine,but when i am in Chinese language and going to settings and changing to English and then starting the app, the app is crashing.

Comment: To diagnose crashes, have a look at the exception stacktrace in logcat.

Comment: Hi it crashing because ,after changing the language, the application is checking if database exists, since its already exist its unable to get Chinese values,actually it should start the app from first and load the chinese database ...i guess what say??